# How To debug Android app on Emulator using NetBeans IDE

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, netbeans6.5

I recently downloaded the latest NetBeans IDE (for MACOSX) and imported/migrated a project over from the ECLIPSE environment.

Everything looks, and works well... except that EMULATOR gets stuck "waiting for the debugger to attach." I tried "Attaching Debugger..." and set the PORT value to every case I've ever read about (8200, 8700, 5555, etc.) but the connection is refused.

I am of the opinion that this is not the preferred way to start a debugging session in NetBeans for Android.

What am I missing?

Comment: UPDATE ->

I restarted the EMULATOR and now the debugger attaches automagically as I would have expected.

BUT when I hit my breakpoint (at least I think thats where this is happening) the Emulator shows a popup indicating that the App has "unexpectedly quit."

The IDE does not appear to think that it is AT the breakpoint...

The DEBUGGER Tab in the IDE shows me MAIN in WAIT, and several other threads all RUNNING.

Comment: Another UPDATE -> I am able to set breakpoints in the MainActivity but get the UNEXPECTED STOPping if I try to achieve a breakpoint in another activity started by Main.

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi to any that have taken a view here...

I have figured out whats been going on.

First: I had failed to add these 'secondary' Activities to the Android Manifest.

Next: I had failed to correctly edit a 'layout'
 xml file stolen from the original ECLIPSE project. The name of an Extended VIEW was 'left over' from the original project and the NetBeans version has a different Pkg name.

So, a big "Duh!" and an even Bigger "Doh!"

Answer (score 0):

You have the newest Netbeans android plugin, right? Might be helpful to explore the forum at the plugin site..