# Netbeans & Android emulator

Tags: android, netbeans, debugging

I set my android emulator to wait for the debugger for my application, so when it starts, the emulator waits writing in output log "`waiting for debugger on port 8100`".

But, I can't find a way to attach the Netbeans debugger to this port nor to the emulator in general...

Please help,
Alban.

Answer (score 0):

There is an item in the Debug menu, labelled 'Attach Debugger...'

This item opens a dialog that lets you provide connection details.

Since multiple debuggers are supported, you may need to explicitly select the 'right debugger', which I assume is the Java Debugger.

There are a couple of gotchas that you might run into:

**The Debugger may not have been activated**. Open the Plugins dialog (Tools->Plugins) and activate the plugins in the 'Java SE' category are all activated.

**The project that starts the emulator may not be debuggable**.  See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374813/how-to-debug-android-app-on-emulator-using-netbeans-ide) for more info.

Comment: Effectively, but I can't find the correct port, connection mode, etc.
Do I have to launch ddms?